# Parse, Check if input matches an objectId

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, parse-platform

so basically I'm trying to see if I can get the text submitted by an input field to match a user's objectId in the input field. Like, say if a user types some numbers and letters in an input field and it's equal to one of the user's objectId's in the Data Browser, then console.log a message...

I was thinking of using a **query** to loop through the users and then retrieve what the user types in the input,

So something like:

```
<input type="text" id="inputObject"></input>

<script>
     var query =  new Parse.Query(Parse.User).id;
     var input = $('#inputObject').val();

     query.find({
       success: function(results) {
           if(query == input) {
            console.log("There has been a match.");
           }
        },
       error: function(results, error) {
            console.log("None found.");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is a users objectid? where do you define such a thing? in js, db or html?

Comment: It's in the data browser of parse.com (an API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thought: Parse User class is secured by default. Make sure the Access Control List permits you to read user data.

Now, if you can read data, try this code:

```
 <script>
     var query =  new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
     var input = $('#inputObject').val();
     query.equalTo("objectId", input);
     query.find({
       success: function(results) {
           console.log("found a user..");
        },
       error: function(results, error) {
            console.log("None found.");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: for some reason, no matter what I type, it displays "found a user..."

Comment: I also used console.log to make sure that the input was being retrieved (i.e: `console.log(input);` and that worked. But I still get the same display.

Comment: Also just to specify, my code is wrapped in a `$('body').delegate('.btn', "click", function() { ... }`

Comment: If it always display "found a user.. ", try this once and let me know what happens, `console.log(results[0].get('UserName')` . Please note here that UserName is a field in class user(You may use any other field). I just want to see if you are actually finding any user or not.

Comment: Weird, I get a:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined `

Comment: Okay I got it. Parse will not throw an error even if an empty array is retrieved. The query will always go in the success method if the query has been implemented correctly. Since your syntax and all that are correct, you are getting `found a user` Can you try it by giving `input` a valid ObjectId and maybe then retrieving the array again?

Comment: Oh great! When I enter a valid ObjectId it outputs the "found a user". However it also gives me and "undefined" for `console.log(results[0].get('objectId'));` and I'm still getting the `'get' of undefined`

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's the best I could try for this problem(But I'll let you know if something strikes me) But Can you please tell me what are you trying to achieve exactly? Maybe I can think of some other way of doing that.. :)